# Why does my mobile website show my desktop site, but when I request desktop site on my phone it shows the mobile site?

Tags: html, css

So When I view my site on my phone it shows the desktop version, but If I request the desktop version when I'm on my phone it will show me the mobile version (scale to my phone.)

I have the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` Which I thought would work.

Here is the code and the site.

[Site Page](https://brightlightning.org/)

[html](https://cdn.brightlightning.org/css/style.css)

[css](http://ps://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficialBrightLightning/website/master/index.html)

If you need any more info the help me with this please comment.

Comment: When I open your website in mobile view  I can only see the desktop version So is this your question that your mobile view is never displayed?

Comment: Yes, but no. If a view my site on a phone it shows the deskstop site, but if I check the "desktop site" button in google chrome it shows the mobile site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to fix it.

This tag is the problem

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The reason why is my sites css has a fullscreen element to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove maximum-scale=1.0 then it might work. In real I am unable to understand what your question is